# Is there an existing algorithm for comparing dates/longs to Minutes?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-date

I want to compare a "now" long/date value minus a "last notification time" long/data value to an integer value representing an interval of minutes before a new notification is made.

I know I cannot simply do this:

```
bool bItIsTime = (iMinutesBetweenNotifications < (lLastNotificationTime - lRightNow));
```

...but what *is* the way to do it. If the value of "now" is 42.2468, would 41.2468 be yesterday at this time? IOW, does 1.00 == 1 day? (in which case 0.1 == 144 minutes, 0.01 == 14.4 minutes, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are extracting the `long` value of the last notification time from a Date or Calendar object, the value is usually the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 GMT. This is also the same units that you get from `System.currentTimeMillis()`. You can do your test like this:

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
bool bItIsTime = iMinutesBetweenNotifications * 60000 // convert to milliseconds
    > now - lLastNotificationTime;
if (bItIsTime) {
    issueNotification();
    lLastNotificationTime = now;
}
```